# Moment of inertia of two linked disks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

It is an easy exercise but I'm not seeing it. I'm asked to find the moment of inertia of two equal disks linked together in such way that one is horizontal and the other one is vertical.

[image]

I tried this

$I= 2 [\frac{1}{2} m r^2 + mr^2]$

But on my book I found this solution
$I= 2 [ mr^2]+\frac{1}{2} m r^2+  \frac{1}{4} m r^2 $

I can't understand why there is that $\frac{1}{4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The moment of inertia with respect to an axis passing vertically through (i.e., perpendicular to) the center of a disk is $\frac{1}{2} m r^2$.  The moment of inertia with respect to an axis passing through the center of a disk in its plane is $\frac{1}{4} m r^2$.  We now use the parallel axis theorem and add $mr^2$ to each moment of inertia to get the total moment of inertia for the system you are describing.  This gives $I = 2mr^2 + \frac{1}{2} mr^2 + \frac{1}{4} m r^2$ as required.